# Подключение USB-устройств к видеокарте

Tags: usb, железо, видеокарта, разъёмы

Неожиданно [узнал](https://edelws.ru/read/news/usb_type_c.html), что если на видеокарте есть порт type c, то к нему можно подключать любые usb-устройства. Вопрос: стоит ли так делать, какие плюсы и минусы у этого действия? А что если подключить usb-хаб, имеющий собственное питание?

Уже проверил, что такая схема действительно работает, но всё же хотел бы выяснить, стоит ли её использовать.

PS: <s>[Этот вопрос на английском.](//hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/12113/13650)</s> [Этот вопрос на английском.](//superuser.com/q/1487328/724113)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мой ответ может быть неполон, так как разные производители могут предполагать разные возможности функциональности данного порта.

1. VirtualLink. Подключение гарнитуры виртуальной реальности. Забавная штука, если высококачественная. Я с удовольствием уже в виртуальной реальности снова побывал в сингапурском океанариуме :)
2. Подключение устройств USB тип С. При этом телефоны заряжаются и доступны для передачи/скачивания данных. Однако, замечу, что "большая флешка" на базе SSD с коннектором данного типа, хоть и определялась в системе и нормально функционировала, всё же работала медленнее, чем через порт от материнской платы.
3. Подключение периферии через HUB. Мыши и клавы работают. Работают мониторы (через переходник, демонстрируя одну и ту же картинку), определялись научные приборы, даже ноутбучную сетевую плату удалось подключить (определялась и настраивалась). Но я не встречал активных тип C хабов, поэтому ничего про собственное питание не скажу

P.S. Если нет шлема, стоит относиться к данному порту как к "дополнительной возможности подключения", не более. C другой стороны, мой планшет при подключении через него заряжается по 9-вольтовому сценарию, а не по 5-вольтовому.

Comment: Я скорее имел в виду, может ли такое подключение вредить устройствам или видеокарте? Просто есть подозрение, что usb3 на материнке несколько глючит, вот и возникла идея подключить к видеокарте, раз уж так можно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет. Видеокарта наверняка подключена, как минимум, 6-штырьковым (а то и 8-ми штырьковым) коннектором к питанию. Так что выход из строя маловероятен. Но, чтобы его полностью нивелировать, не подключайте 9-вольтовые устройства и хабы в то время, когда чересчур нагружаете видеокарту.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualLink - можешь как-то пояснить, о чём там речь? Особенно смущает фраза _"VirtualLink has no USB 2.0 channels active, instead providing a higher speed USB 3.1 Gen 2 (SuperSpeed+) over the same A6, A7, B7, B6 pins."._

Comment: Вроде бы разобрались: https://superuser.com/a/1487507/724113

Comment: @Qwertiy насколько я понимаю, в классическом type C две линии USB3, с переворотом на 180, плюс линия USB2, переворот обеспечивается коммутацией. Здесь же убрали USB2, переворот возложили на сам VL, взамен - третья линия, что позволяет поднять, как пропускную способность, так и мощность. На совместимости сказываться, по идее, не должно, - работали же у нас мыши через хаб.